# Auto fill text when record is being used in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet where I put data every day. columns A to J are always different so that is handwork, but the last 2 columns are always the same.

In column K there is always the word "Password" and in column L there is always the word "Callcenter"

Is it possible when I enter text in the records that those words are automatically filled in columns K and J?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways of doing what you want. Here is code I adapted from one of my projects. It will copy all formats from the row above and fill in the two cells you want filled. The action can be expanded to do more.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ' 150
    
    With Target
        If .Address = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp) _
                           .Offset(1).Address Then
            Cancel = True
            .ClearComments
            .Rows(.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Cells(.Row, 11).Resize(, 2).Value = Array("Password", "Callcenter")
            SetComment .Offset(1)
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub SetComment(Cell As Range)
    ' 150

    Dim Cmt             As String
    Dim Pos             As Integer
    
    Cmt = "Add a row:" & Chr(10) & _
          "Double-click on this cell to add a new row."
    
    Pos = InStr(Cmt, ":")
    With Cell
        .ClearComments
        .AddComment Cmt
        If Pos Then .Comment.Shape.TextFrame.Characters(1, Pos) _
                    .Font.Bold = True
    End With
End Sub
```

The code must be installed in the code sheet of the worksheet on which you want the action. It won't work if installed elsewhere. In the VB Editor's Project Explorer pane the module already exists and will have a double name like *Sheet1 (Sheet1)* with the second name being the one you may have given to the tab.

This line of code specifies the column:
`If .Address = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)`, here column A. You can change the column.

Now, when you double-click on the cell below the last used cell in the specified column - and only there - a row will be inserted at the double-clicked cell, copying all formats from the row above it and adding the two words you want. The code will also add a comment in the cell below the new row, guiding your next double-click.

Yes, it would be possible to add the two words into a macro that runs after you finish your entry. But that is after whereas this is before and has the advantage of formatting your cells. It really depends upon your work flow.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I found also another method!

Answer (score 0):

This was the method I found and also worked!

```
Range(Range("K2"), Range("K" & lastRow)).FillDown
Range(Range("L2"), Range("L" & lastRow)).FillDown
```